# Too much load on kafka partition (extra load on single partition)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Suppose, there is trade capture application. The application consumes message via kafka. The partition id is stock-id (eg google, apple, tesla). This works fine in normal days. Suppose there is bad news for company and people are selling stocks for X company. Then in this case, all the messages would come to single partition during that trading session or day.
 How do i handle, this efficiently? Can we apply multiple consumers to same partition? 
its due to overloaded partition on random day. We have more than dozens of partitions along with dozens of consumers. All the partitions/ consumers are equally distributed everytime throughout the year. Its when there is sudden spike of data in single partition which happens once in month or quarterly .

Comment: Is the problem an overloaded partition (due to which kafka broker that handles this partition can't handle all read/write requests) OR is the problem a single consumer instance, that can't handle records fast enough which causes lag?

Comment: its due to overloaded partition on random day. We have more than dozens of partitions along with dozens of consumers. All the partitions/ consumers are equally distributed everytime throughout the year. Its when there is sudden spike of data in single partition which happens once in month or quarterly . @MirekPluta

Answer (score 1):

> Can we apply multiple consumers to same partition

Not in the same consumer group, no.

---

The only way to reasonably handle this is to increase `max.poll.records` and other consumer properties to consume faster from that partition, and/or all partitions. Unfortunately, you won't know ahead of time which partition will get "overloaded".

The other alternative is to redesign your topic(s) such that "stock tickers" are not your partition ID and whatever you do choose as your partitioning strategy is not driven by end-user behavior that is out of your control (or otherwise define your own Paritioner class).

Comment: I made the above example to understand the problem. My question is little generic. Is there a way to handle this scenario more gracefully if this problem occurs even after very nice implementation of partition key using our own custom partitioner class @OneCricketeer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If there's considerable lag in any partition, your only option is to configure the consumer to read data faster, or start dropping events

Comment: @OneCricketerr : not talking about lags. Talking about uneven distribution in some worst case scenarios . Some partition are having too many messages to consume while other partition has less messages., even after properly implementing partition key or class. They partitioning logic works 99 percent of the times. What if someday, some partitions recieved more messages compared to other partition

Comment: "having too many messages to consume" is what lag means, due to uneven distribution, or not, and regardless of any partitioning scheme. There's no other options here